# Getting error while calling API from .NET application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I want to call an API from a .NET application, but unfortunately I am getting an error:

> "Script7002:XMLhttpREQUEST:Network Error 0x80070005, Access Denied."

If I am testing the API with the "Advanced Rest Client (ARC)" Chrome extension, then I am getting the proper response. How do I resolve this issue?

Here below I am giving the code which I used to call the API from .NET application.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function ShowCurrentTime() {
        alert("start");

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://XXXXXXXXXXXX/api/xx/xxxxxx",
            dataType: "application/json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                "Username": "xxxxxx",
                "Password": "xxxxxxx",
                "Code": "xxx"
            },

            success: function (r) { alert("success"); }
        });

        alert("finished");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The error is because you've not authenticated with the API properly. Exactly how you do that will depend on how the API is configured

Answer (score -1):

Try this option in Internet Explorer:

Security area (*Internet Options* → *Security*). Enable the setting *Miscellaneous* → *Access data sources across domains*.